# Logging commands executed with Invoke-Command

Tags: sql, powershell

I recently hacked together a process that would spin off multiple remote installations on servers.  We are looking for a way to install SQL Patches on 100+ remote servers automatically.  I was able to make a successful pass of this last Saturday.  It worked very well.

I am not a PowerShell expert or even novice.  I was able to get something working and would like to expand on it.  The command below is what I am issuing in PowerShell and would like to put some logging like each servers start and end time of applying the patch.  I would like to save this to a central table that all servers can connect to.

My question is does anyone have any good resources that would get me down the path of what I am looking for or could help me advance my skills to improve my process.

The -ComputerName parameter is pathed to a txt file with a list of server names that I want patched in this group.

The -ScriptBlock parameter is pathed to a batch file on the remove server that has the command to execute the SQL Patch via the command line.
     `"D:\DBA\SQLPatching\SQL_2012\SP3_CU2\SQLServer2012-KB3137746-x64.exe" /quiet /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /Action=Patch /AllInstances`

Thanks

```
 $jobWRM = invoke-command -computerName (get-content D:\DBA\SQLPatching\May2016\LLE\ServerLists\ServerList_EIQDBS01_1.txt) -scriptblock {D:\DBA\SQLPatching\SQL_2012\SP3_CU2\Patch-SQL2012_SP3_CU2.bat} -jobname WinRM -throttlelimit 16 -AsJob
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just catch the execution state, you could throw those computernames in a variable and foreach through them while writing completion out to a log.

If you want errors to give you more depth in troubleshooting, Pssessions will give you errors back (not sure if the batch file you list will give you good troubleshooting data though).

You can find examples of both of these approaches on the web

[ForEach](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html)

[PSSessions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2269.quick-guide-to-powershell-v2-remoting-with-pssession.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't really help with logging and tracking times, however. He is on the right track with using jobs already. He just needs to add in waiting and logging...

Comment: Agreed, Austin. I kinda figured the foreach loop would be able to do that. Looking back at the post, I should given an example of how t write off to a file the servername, time, and maybe some description of the status.

Comment: I was actually thinking this is 90% of what he needs:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849735.aspx